# How can I change font-family and size without css in table?

Tags: html

I want to change font-family and font-size without css in table.
I have to use only html.

Comment: Hi KTI, welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not entirely clear what you're asking, and the general site policy is that you show what you've already tried so that users don't repeat methods that won't work for you, as well as the code you're working with, or an example snippet of it.

Comment: You can use the `style` option in the HTML tag to use CSS without needing an external file: `<p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20px;></p>`

Comment: umm....I'm sorry, I want to change text without css. I know css, but I can't use style tag. For example, I have to write instead <table style="border:1px"> of <table border="1px" >. style="font-size:9px;" -> ??

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: you can use javascript or jquery methods,or even it's not enough change your browser font-size & font-family settings.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Font Styles</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="purple">
<ul>
    <li> <font color="pink"> Trial Font </font> </li>
    <li> <font size="100px" color="white">Trial Font</font> </li>
    <li> <font face="Ebrima">Trial Font</font> </li>
</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is asking about changing the font family and size in a **table** … and there isn't one in your code only answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Edit the html border and font family

```html
<html>
<head>

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}
--->
</STYLE>

</head>
<body>

<table border=1>
<tr><td> test 1 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 2 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 3 </td></tr>
<tr><td> test 4 </td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know css and <style> tag, but I shouldn't use style tag or inline style sheet

Comment: What I posted works. Try it out in the Run code snippet and change the font to something else and see the change

Comment: You're using CSS... so you haven't answered the question.